# Strange black outline on all S.O and on browsers

Tags: windows-10, outline

something very, very strange has happened. 
Since a few hours, my Chrome (also IE) shows a different default outline on input. 
Inspecting the code I saw that the outline set is as follows:

outline: -webkit-focus-ring-color auto 1px

and result is like this:
[image]

happens both incognito and in navigation with or without extensions.

how can I restore it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Google Chrome version 83 release notes there is one interesting point:

**Updated form control elements**

> ...
>   Chrome 83 introduces a new set of default settings. These settings allow effortless ways for Developers to keep their controls looking great, consistent, and widely usable.
>
> If you encounter any incompatibility issues with this change, the UseLegacyFormControls 
>   policy will revert to the previous default settings.

https://cloud.google.com/docs/chrome-enterprise/policies/?policy=UseLegacyFormControls

One may switch back new control styling but they promise to make it mandatory in next v84 release ((

```
chrome://flags 
#form-controls-refresh to Disabled
```

That worked for me.

Comment: Thanks a lot it's work!